# Java SMTP accept badly formatted emails

Tags: java, email, smtp

I am using SubethaSMTP to proxy smtp emails. I have an application sending emails to this proxy.

It happens that sometimes the application send malformed emails (for historical reasons).
This I cannot change. This is a buggy external solutions.
I am handling the received emails and route them based on the email value.

My issue is when I call the following method on the received emails:

```
Address[] tos = message.getRecipients(RecipientType.TO);
```

When there are malformed emails in the recipients list, I cannot get the list because I receive an exception.

My objective is to get all the emails and correct the malformed ones.
But because of the exception, I cannot get them.

Is there a way to get all the recipient emails even if there are some bad ones? Just read them without any issue? Is it possible to bypass the controls?

The stack trace is: The email address is @TEST(value) . this is generated by the external application. I'd like to be able to get it, and remove it from the list, and correct it to resend it

```
javax.mail.internet.AddressException: Missing local name in string ``@TEST''
    at javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress.checkAddress(InternetAddress.java:1216)
    at javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress.parse(InternetAddress.java:1096)
    at javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress.parseHeader(InternetAddress.java:663)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.getAddressHeader(MimeMessage.java:733)
    at javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage.getRecipients(MimeMessage.java:565)
    at MessageHandler.done(TestMessageHandler.java:128)
    at org.subethamail.smtp.server.Session.endMessageHandler(Session.java:513)
    at org.subethamail.smtp.server.Session.resetMessageState(Session.java:490)
    at org.subethamail.smtp.command.DataCommand.execute(DataCommand.java:84)
    at org.subethamail.smtp.server.RequireTLSCommandWrapper.execute(RequireTLSCommandWrapper.java:30)
    at org.subethamail.smtp.server.CommandHandler.handleCommand(CommandHandler.java:99)
    at org.subethamail.smtp.server.Session.runCommandLoop(Session.java:244)
    at org.subethamail.smtp.server.Session.run(Session.java:145)
```

Comment: Please show the stacktrace

Comment: thanks I have added the stack trace

Comment: I think there is no way, because MimeMessage.getRecipients() checks the validity of an InternetAddress. It must be done because that is the returntype